# Difference between NULL, 0 ,False and ''?

Tags: php, python

What is the exact difference between `null`, `0`, `false`, and an empty string in PHP? Is `null` similar to `None` in python?

Comment: And no, it is not similar to `None` in Python, which is an actual value. `null` means there is no value at all.

Comment: Like @MartijnPieters said `None` is a Object in Python and will use up some memory.. Well the `NULL` in PHP and other programming languages which uses `NULL` will clear the memory for that variable some languages will use some kind of garbage collector... Python `None` is more similair to PHP's `StdClass` and basically Python syntax to check for None `if <Object> is None:` is more or less this in PHP `if <Object> instanceof StdClass`

Comment: @ozgur: why did this need reopening? This is basically a PHP question, the minor 'is this the same as Python's None' angle has already been addressed in a comment and doesn't require a separate answer. If you feel a post needs re-opening, please do let me know and we can discuss this. We could add a separate duplicate target about the nature of the Python `None` object, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after massive comments and then poof deletion of them... may as well try to help you out.

`null` is the absence of value.

`0` can be a numeric value, or a representation of a boolean `FALSE`, or a string.  PHP doesn't really have variable typing, so depending on what you are checking for using `==0` or `===0` or `==false` or `===false` may be appropriate.

You may want to read over this - https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/  as well as the PHP manual for `isset()` and `empty()`